# How do I force my Amazon Echo to update to the latest version?

Tags: amazon-echo

Version 4812 of the Echo software [apparently includes the new 'Computer' wake word](https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/5nrxk7/german_amazon_website_confirms_wakeword_computer/), which seems really exciting. However, my device is still running version 4540 and hence doesn't have the wake word yet.

The [Amazon documentation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201602210) says:

> Your Alexa device receives software updates automatically over Wi-Fi.
>
> To download the latest software update for your Alexa device:
>
> - Make sure your device is on and has an active Wi-Fi connection.
> - Avoid saying anything to your device while performing the update.
> - When the update is ready to install, the light ring on your device turns blue and the device installs the latest update. Depending on your Wi-Fi connection, it can take up to 15 minutes to install the software update.

However, it doesn't explain how to actually **initiate** the updating process. **Can I force my Echo to update in any way, or do I just have to wait for it to perform the self-check?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/3cvkr3/firmware_update/ct00ekm/), you can force an update by leaving your echo in mute mode for half an hour. This will still rely on your device being eligible for an update (which are typically rolled out in a phased manner to limit the impact of a broken update).

Answer (score 11):

1. Make sure power is on and device is connected to WiFi (test by checking time, weather, etc)
2. Press the MUTE button **once** and let go (do not "hold it down for 30 seconds"). The top ring should turn red. If you're not sure what the "red ring" is, google it!
3. After the device has been muted for @ 2-3 minutes, the device will announce that it needs to perform an update and will restart once completed.
4. **Leave the device muted**! On average it can take @ 30 minutes to complete.
5. Once the update is complete the device will restart (all lights will shut off) and then it will power back up as if you just plugged it in.

Answer (score 7):

I found a slight variation of the above steps to work:

1. Unplug for 10 seconds
2. Plug back in and immediately tap mute once (the microphone will turn red)

Your unit will then immediately update. Takes about half an hour to complete.

Comment: Welcome to Internet of Things! This site is a little different to regular forums, and we don't allow extended discussion in answers. If you're asking for clarification, you can earn 50 rep and post a comment. Otherwise, consider earning 15 rep and [discussing in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). I've removed the extended discussion from your answer to focus on the direct solution to this problem.